# Is there a way to completely delete fields in awk, so that extra delimiters do not print?

Tags: awk

Consider the following command:

```sh
$ gawk -F"\t" "BEGIN{OFS=\"\t\"}{$2=$3=\"\"; print $0}" Input.tsv
```

When I set `$2 = $3 = ""`, the intended effect is to get the same effect as writing:

```
print $1,$4,$5...$NF
```

However, what actually happens is that I get two empty fields, with the extra field delimiters still printing.

Is it possible to actually delete `$2` and `$3`?

Note: If this was on Linux in `bash`, the correct statement above would be the following, but Windows does not handle single quotes well in `cmd.exe`.

```sh
$ gawk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$2=$3=""; print $0}' Input.tsv
```

Comment: You should use single quotes for the outer set, then you don't have to escape the double quotes within the script. If you're using double quotes for the outer set so you can embed shell variables, use `-v` to do variable passing instead.

Comment: I'm using awk in Windows. Cmd.exe doesn't play well with single quotes for some reason.

Comment: I did this 10+ years ago, (I think). try doing a  `$2=$3="";$0=$0`. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, Tried, no luck. Probably the version of awk has changed. Thanks for suggestion though!

Comment: OK, now just thinking out-side-the-box ;->, `$2=$3="XYZ"; sub("\tXYZ\t", "", $0); $0=$0; print`. Not sure if you'd need both `\t` in the sub. Also, if you have the orginal awk book, check there, I thought that is where I learned $0=$0. Maybe I'm forgetting a step. Good luck.

Comment: This question was run on Windows when I asked this question, so it needs to be `""`.

Comment: Rolled back and updated to absorb the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an oldie but goodie.

As Jonathan points out, you can't delete fields in the middle, but you can replace their contents with the contents of other fields. And you can make a reusable function to handle the deletion for you.

```
$ cat test.awk
function rmcol(col,     i) {
  for (i=col; i<NF; i++) {
    $i = $(i+1)
  }
  NF--
}

{
  rmcol(3)
}

1

$ printf 'one two three four\ntest red green blue\n' | awk -f test.awk
one two four
test red blue
```

Comment: Decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX. It will delete the last field in some awks, be ignored in other awks, and could do anything else and still be POSIX compliant.

Comment: @EdMorton: I appreciate the issue, it's not specified by the standard and should be avoided in portable scripts. I tested this with gawk, mawk, nawk and busybox awk which all behave as expected, do you know any awk's that do not support this behavior?

Comment: @Thor MacOS/BSD awk for one.

Comment: @EdMorton, actually I created this answer on FreeBSD, and this function works on macOS's awk as well (which came over from FreeBSD a few years ago). I suspect where you might see different behaviour would be in older SysV systems. Alas, I have none of those to test with at the moment.

Comment: I'm on MacOS right now. `awk --version` outputs 
`awk version 20070501` and 
`echo 'a b c' | awk '{NF--}1'` outputs `a b c` while `echo 'a b c' | gawk '{NF--}1'` outputs `a b`. Your script does produce the output you say it does though - not sure why off the top of my head but it can't be the `NF--` doing it.

Comment: Ah, the `NF--` DOES have an impact but only if you do something to modify a field as you're doing and as this does: `echo 'a b c' | awk '{NF--;$1=$1}1'` outputs 
`a b`

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, that's because `$0` is already set by the time your first action is evaluated. You'll see different results with `echo 'a b c' | awk '{NF--;$1=$1}1'`. Note that `NF` is still being decremented, the difference is when `$0` is constructed. I see that the behaviour is also different if the awk script is loaded from a file (`-f`) rather than from the command line. Whee, quirks! Gotta love 'em.

Comment: `echo 'a b c' | awk '{$1=$1;NF--}1'` produces the same output `a b`. **undefined** behavior indeed - inexplicable might be a better term! :-).

Answer (score 7):

You can't delete fields in the middle, but you can delete fields at the end, by decrementing `NF`.

So you can shift all the later fields down to overwrite `$2` and `$3` then decrement `NF` by two, which erases the last two fields:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 | awk '{for(i=2; i<NF-1; ++i) $i=$(i+2); NF-=2; print $0}'
1 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are just looking to remove columns, you can use `cut`:

```sh
$ cut -f 1,4- file.txt
```

To emulate `cut`:

```
$ awk -F "\t" '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i != 2 && i != 3) { if (i == NF) printf $i"\n"; else printf $i"\t" } }' file.txt
```

Similarly:

```sh
$ awk -F "\t" '{ delim =""; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i != 2 && i != 3) { printf delim $i; delim = "\t"; } printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

HTH

Comment: The last example prints a trailing tab. `{for (...) {printf delim $i; delim = "\t"}; printf "\n"}`

Comment: I'm concerned about the gsub because there are other fields that are legitimately empty and I DO want the multiple delimiters.

Comment: @merlin2011 See my changes. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to remove fields like you do and remove extra spaces with `gsub`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } { $2 = $3 = ""; gsub( /\s+/, "\t" ); print }' input-file
```

Answer (score 1):

In the addition of the answer by Suicidal Steve I'd like to suggest one more solution but using `sed` instead `awk`.

It seems more complicated than usage of `cut` as it was suggested by Steve. But it was the better solution because `sed -i` allows editing in-place.

```
$ sed -i 's/\(.*,\).*,.*,\(.*\)/\1\2/' FILENAME
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do it in Awk without using a loop is to use `gsub` on `$0` to combine adjacent `FS`:

```
$ echo {1..10} | awk '{$2=$3=""; gsub(FS"+",FS); print}'
1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove fields 2 and 3 from a given input file (assuming a tab field separator), you can remove the fields from $0 using `gensub` and regenerate it as follows:

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}\
             {$0=gensub(/[^\t]*\t/,"",3);\
              $0=gensub(/[^\t]*\t/,"",2);\
              print}' Input.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the goal is to remove the extra delimiters, then you can use `tr` on Linux. Example:

```sh
$ echo "1,2,,,5" | tr -s ','
```

```
1,2,5
```

Answer (score 0):

The method presented in the [answer of ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38311342/8344060) has some problems:

- every assignment of `$i = $(i+1)` forces awk to rebuild the record `$0`. This implies that if you have 100 fields and you want to delete field 10, you rebuild the record 90 times.
- changing the value of `NF` manually is not posix compliant and leads to undefined behaviour (as is mentioned in the comments).

A somewhat more cumbersome, but stable robust way to delete a set of columns would be:

**a single column:**

```
awk -v del=3 '
    BEGIN{FS=fs;OFS=ofs}
    { b=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if(i!=del) b=(b?b OFS:"") $i; $0=b }
    # do whatever you want to do
   ' file
```

**multiple columns:**

```
awk -v del=3,5,7 '
    BEGIN{FS=fs;OFS=ofs; del="," del ","}
    { b=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if (del !~ ","i",") b=(b?b OFS:"") $i; $0=b }
    # do whatever you want to do
   ' file
```

Comment: I think gawk at least only rebuilds `$0` (and `$n`) when needed.  E.g. if you blank out `$1`, then it remains blank until `$0` is re-read, after which it becomes `$2`.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo one two three four five six|awk '{
print $0
is3=$3
$3=""
print $0
print is3
}'
```

one two three four five six

one two  four five six

three