# Duplicate Lines 2 times and transpose from row to column

Tags: awk

I will like to duplicate each line 2 times and print values of column 5 and 6 separated.( transpose values of column 5 and 6 from column to row ) for each line

I mean value on column 5 (first line) value in column 6 ( second line)

**Input File**

```
08,1218864123180000,3201338573,VV,22,27
08,1218864264864000,3243738789,VV,15,23
08,1218864278580000,3244738513,VV,3,13
08,1218864310380000,3243938789,VV,15,23
08,1218864324180000,3244538513,VV,3,13
08,1218864334380000,3200538561,VV,22,27
```

**Desired Output**

```
08,1218864123180000,3201338573,VV,22
08,1218864123180000,3201338573,VV,27
08,1218864264864000,3243738789,VV,15
08,1218864264864000,3243738789,VV,23
08,1218864278580000,3244738513,VV,3
08,1218864278580000,3244738513,VV,13
08,1218864310380000,3243938789,VV,15
08,1218864310380000,3243938789,VV,23
08,1218864324180000,3244538513,VV,3
08,1218864324180000,3244538513,VV,13
08,1218864334380000,3200538561,VV,22
08,1218864334380000,3200538561,VV,27
```

I use this code to duplicate the lines 2 times, but i cant'n figer out the condition with values of column 5 and 6

```
awk '{print;print}' file
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeatedly print the start of a line for each of the last N fields where N is 2 in this case:

```
$ awk -v n=2 '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        base = $0
        sub("("FS"[^"FS"]+){"n"}$","",base)
        for (i=NF-n+1; i<=NF; i++) {
            print base, $i
        }
    }
' file
08,1218864123180000,3201338573,VV,22
08,1218864123180000,3201338573,VV,27
08,1218864264864000,3243738789,VV,15
08,1218864264864000,3243738789,VV,23
08,1218864278580000,3244738513,VV,3
08,1218864278580000,3244738513,VV,13
08,1218864310380000,3243938789,VV,15
08,1218864310380000,3243938789,VV,23
08,1218864324180000,3244538513,VV,3
08,1218864324180000,3244538513,VV,13
08,1218864334380000,3200538561,VV,22
08,1218864334380000,3200538561,VV,27
```

Comment: GNU awk only but ++ for making me use the brain on a Sunday morning.

Comment: Thanks but there's nothing gawk-specific about that, it'll work in any POSIX awk

Answer (score 2):

In this simple case where the last field has to be removed and placed on the last line, you can do

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{ x = $6; NF = 5; print; $5 = x; print }'
```

Here `-F ,` and `-v OFS=,` will set the input and output field separators to a comma, respectively, and the code does

```
{
  x = $6    # remember sixth field
  NF = 5    # Set field number to 5, so the last one won't be printed
  print     # print those first five fields
  $5 = x    # replace value of fifth field with remembered value of sixth
  print     # print modified line
}
```

This approach can be extended to handle fields in the middle with a function like the one in the accepted answer of  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693608/is-there-a-way-to-completely-delete-fields-in-awk-so-that-extra-delimiters-do-n).

**EDIT:** As Ed notes in the comments, writing to `NF` is not explicitly defined to trigger a rebuild of `$0` (the whole-line record that `print` prints) in the POSIX standard. The above code works with GNU awk and mawk, but with BSD awk (as found on *BSD and probably Mac OS X) it fails to do anything.

So to be standards-compliant, we have to be a little more explicit and force awk to rebuild `$0` from the modified field state. This can be done by assigning to any of the field variables `$1`...`$NF`, and it's common to use `$1=$1` when this problem pops up in other contexts (for example: when only the field separator needs to be changed but not any of the data):

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{ x = $6; NF = 5; $1 = $1; print; $5 = x; print }'
```

I've tested this with GNU awk, mawk and BSD awk (which are all the awks I can lay my hands on), and I believe this to be covered by [the awk bit in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) where it says "setting any other field causes the re-evaluation of $0" right at the top. Mind you, the spec could be more explicit on this point, and I'd be interested to test if more exotic awks behave the same way.

Comment: The effect of reducing the value of NF is undefined behavior per POSIX. It will delete the last field(s) in some awks, be ignored in other awks, and could do anything else and still be POSIX compliant.

Comment: Well, what do you know: POSIX awk is somewhat weird on this issue, and BSD awk does indeed forget to trigger a rebuild of `$0` on assignment to `NF` (this can probably bite users of OSX). Fortunately, POSIX does define a way to be explicit about this, so I'll just put that in.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(considering that your Input_file always is same as shown and you need to print every time 1st four fields and then rest of the fields(one by one printing along with 1st four)).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$2,$3,$4,$i}}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU awk):

```
awk '{print gensub(/((.*,).*),/,"\\1\n\\2",1)}' file
```

Replace the last comma by a newline and the previous fields less the penultimate.