# Merge 3 columns into 1

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have 1 csv file with 16 columns that looks like this :

```
WEB QUEST|Lazaro|Martinez|0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

I´ve tried to merge 3 columns together with awk and sed but for some reason I still don get the desire output :

```
WEB QUEST|Lazaro Martinez 0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

when I tried `awk -F "|" '{print $1,"|"$2,$3,$4,"|"$5...}'`

for some reason some spaces are added in each | and this is the output i get

```
EB QUEST |Maria Valencia Loza |Consultor de ventas | Mexico |DF | 55457110 | 55450327 | 4003071 | evalencia@webquest.com.mx | 05/10/1999 | 0 |0 |0
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Which are your desired output? "," may is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` with matching the first four fields:

```
sed 's/\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)/\1|\2 \3 \4/' <<<"WEB QUEST|Lazaro|Martinez|0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0"
```

will output:

```
WEB QUEST|Lazaro Martinez 0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

Answer (score 4):

The comma in Awk `print` adds a field separator `OFS`. To simply concatenate strings, omit the commas.

```
awk -F "|" '{print $1 "|" $2 $3 $4 "|" $5...}'
```

Probably a better approach is to set `OFS="|"` and simply shift out the third and fourth fields, as explained in [Is there a way to completely delete fields in awk, so that extra delimiters do not print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693608/is-there-a-way-to-completely-delete-fields-in-awk-so-that-extra-delimiters-do-n)

Answer (score 2):

With bash and GNU sed:

```
sed -e's/|/ /2'{,} file
```

**Explanation:**

```
-e's/|/ /2'{,}
```

expands to

```
-e's/|/ /2' -e's/|/ /2'
```

(see [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)); so it replaces **second** pipe with space **twice**, thus 2nd, 3rd and 4th fields will be merged.

Answer (score 1):

You can join column 2,3 and 4 like this, but it will leave you with empty column 3 and 4:

```
awk -F\| -v OFS='|' '{$2=$2" "$3" "$4;$3=$4="";print $0}' file
WEB QUEST|Lazaro Martinez 0|||Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

It can be solved by printing the only fixed first fields, and the loop trough the rest.

```
awk -F\| '{a=$2" "$3" "$4;$3=$4="";printf "%s"FS"%s",$1,a;for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) printf FS"%s",$i}' file
WEB QUEST|Lazaro Martinez 0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

You can remove empty column like this, but if there are empty column in the original they are gone too:

```
awk -F\| -v OFS='|' '{$2=$2" "$3" "$4;$3=$4="";gsub(/[|]+/,FS)}1' file
WEB QUEST|Lazaro Martinez 0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

Answer (score 0):

Though your full requirement is not clear but by seeing your expected sample output I got to know you don't want space in expected output if this is the case then you need to set `OFS` as `|`  as follows. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1=" "
  FS=OFS="|"
  re="(.*)\\|\\|\\|(.*)"
}
prev{
  print gensub(re,"\\1|\\2","1",$0)
}
{
  $2=$2 s1 $3 s1 $4
  $3=$4=""
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(prev){
    print gensub(re,"\\1|\\2","1",$0)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried with `awk` and `sed`; however you are not binded to those, you can use `read`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<file.csv
while IFS="|" read -r foo var1 var2 var3 bar <&3; do
  printf "%s|%s %s %s|%s\n" "${foo}" "${var1}" "${var2}" "${var3}" "${bar}"
done
exec 3>&-
```

Input:

```
WEB QUEST|Lazaro|Martinez|0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

Ouptut:

```
WEB QUEST|Lazaro Martinez 0|Consultor de ventas|Mexico|DF|55457110|55450327|53445299|0|05/10/1999|0|0|0
```

N.B. The exec part is just there as "Best practice", you can achieve the same result without it

E.G.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="|" read -r foo var1 var2 var3 bar; do
  printf "%s|%s %s %s|%s\n" "${foo}" "${var1}" "${var2}" "${var3}" "${bar}"
done <file.csv
```

Comment: `while read` is pathologically slow in Bash. You really want to prefer a proper tool like `sed` or Awk.